# Replicate SQL Server CLR Function

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr, transactional-replication

Is it possible to replicate a CLR Function using Transactional (or Merge) Replication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. See: [Publishing Data and Database Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152559.aspx)